# EnableCors failing in WebApi 5.2.3 for specific apicontrollers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

So I followed the following tutorials:

- [enable-cors-in-webapi-2](https://coderwall.com/p/jspmzq/enable-cors-in-webapi-2)
- [ASPNET-WebAPI-Enable-Cors](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-WebAPI-Enable-Cors-666b88eb)
- [enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Each of them described a way to EnableCors for a controller, or you can add by global.

I followed the steps outlined in all 3 of them where in my App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs file I entered the following:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.EnableCors();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "", action = "Get" }
    );
}
```

And in my controller I added in:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:50247", headers: "*", methods: "*")] 
public class TestController : ApiController
{ ... }
```

But when I went to run the program it gave me the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49705/api/Test/GetTestData. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:50247' is therefore not allowed access.

But when I make the following addition to the App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs to make EnableCors throughout the entire app:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
            origins: "*",
            headers: "*",
            methods: "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
     // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

It worked. But if makes my decorated EnableCors attribute on my api controllers useless.

When I removed the [EnableCors] attribute from my apicontroller:

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{ ... }
```

It worked, because of what I did globally. Is there a reason for why this happened? Did a bug occur when upgrading from webapi 5.2.2 to 5.2.3?

The project is new using asp.net webapi start up templates in visual studio 2013.